# How Update maven-metadata file in nexus programmaticaly

Tags: java, maven, nexus, aether, maven-metadata

I want to update maven-metadata.xml file in my nexus server programmatically. Is there any way I can do this? Can I use eclipse aether API for this?

Comment: Why do you like to do that? Checked in Nexus to recreate the metadata task?

Comment: Won't nexus just overwrite the metadata the next time the task runs?

Comment: When I deleted a version of an artifact from nexus repository, the metadata file is not get updated. The deleted version is the latest version in maven-metadata.xml file. I tried "Rebuild metadata" option. But it doesn't worked.

Comment: Which version of Nexus do you use? Do you get any error message in the log file of Nexus?

Answer (score 2):

The maven metadata files are maintained by Maven. Nexus updates them on deletion and has a scheduled task that can correct the files as well.

However depending on the way you delete the files, the metadata might not get updated. E.g. if you just delete the files in the storage and dont use the Nexus application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Nexus restAPI call to have Nexus rebuild metadata after a deploy, a `DELETE` request to `/service/local/metadata/repositories/<repo-id>/content`.

For example:

```
curl -v -u userID:password -X DELETE http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/metadata/repositories/snapshots/content/com/foo/some/artifact
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled onto this with the same problem and thought I'd share my solution for the next person in my shoes. We have an application where we upload artifacts to a Nexus repository using the REST API, and this does not create the proper maven-metadata.xml files. For example, for com/test/artifact version 2.0.0, it creates com/test/artifact/2.0.0/maven-metadata.xml but not com/test/artifact/maven-metadata.xml. Nexus has a 'Repair - Rebuild Maven repository metadata' task which will do what you want. Unfortunately there is no REST API to create tasks, only to list and run. I monitored network traffic while creating this task in the web UI and came up with this solution in the form of a bash snippet:

```
# create the task
response=$(curl \
  --silent \
  --fail \
  --user $NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"action":"coreui_Task","method":"create","data":[{"id":"NX.coreui.model.Task-1","typeId":"repository.maven.rebuild-metadata","enabled":true,"name":"rebuild maven metadata","alertEmail":"","notificationCondition":"FAILURE","schedule":"manual","properties":{"repositoryName":"maven-hosted","groupId":"","artifactId":"","baseVersion":"","rebuildChecksums":"false"},"recurringDays":[],"startDate":null,"timeZoneOffset":"+00:00"}],"type":"rpc","tid":0}' \
  http://$NEXUS_SERVER/service/extdirect)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  taskid=$(echo $response | jq -r .result.data.id)
  if [[ "$taskid" != "null" ]]; then
    # run the task
    curl \
      --silent \
      --user $NEXUS_USERNAME:$NEXUS_PASSWORD \
      --header 'accept: application/json' \
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --request 'POST' \
      --data '' \
      http://$NEXUS_SERVER/service/rest/v1/tasks/${taskid}/run
  fi
fi
```

We're using Nexus OSS 3.41.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is to use a NEXUS script.
I posted this script via NEXUS REST (POST v1/script)

```
{
"name": "rebuild-maven-metadata-by-script",
"content": "import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.MavenMetadataRebuildFacet;
            import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
    
            log.info('rebuild-maven-metadata-by-script started');
            def request = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args);
            assert request.repoName: 'repoName parameter is required';
            assert request.groupId: 'groupId parameter is required';
            assert request.artifactId: 'artifactId parameter is required';
            def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get(request.repoName);
            MavenMetadataRebuildFacet mavenHostedFacet = repo.facet(MavenMetadataRebuildFacet.class);
            mavenHostedFacet.rebuildMetadata(request.groupId, request.artifactId, null, false, false);
            log.info('rebuild-maven-metadata-by-script completed');",
"type": "groovy"
}
```

The script has parameters for repository name, groupId and artifactId.
It can then be invoked via NEXUS REST (POST /v1/script/{name}/run)

I am using NEXUS OSS 3.62.0